# Are there any drivers/tweaked drivers for a Nividia GTX 965M on Windows XP?

Tags: drivers, gpu

Are there any drivers/tweaked drivers for a nvidia GTX 965M? (microsoft surface book). If not I'll have to install XP inside of windows 10 on hyperV/virtualbox or use ESXI if it does not expect a full intel hardware setup.

Comment: I *very* much doubt Windows XP will run properly on your Surface Book. Don’t do this to yourself, seriously. // Also, there are no official XP drivers at all for 900M series GPUs.

Comment: OP, what's your end goal?  Run some software for XP?  Probably an old game?  HyperV is built into Windows 10.  I'm guessing a game because you want 3D support.  You have almost nothing to lose if you build a VM in HyperV to run whatever program.  Search sites for the program, someone may have solved this, or at least virtualization of it.  Also, your Surface has Intel processor, the thing that would prevent ESXI from working would be if the processor does not support virtualization.  ESXI may be the only virtualization option with 3D support.  Also, consider vista drivers.

Comment: I've had problems with windows 10 before and don't want to go there again. I'm trying it again on a borrowed laptop before buying. I know there are few options around since XP is old. I want to use XP but not as a laptop always (i.e tablet). a mobile phone is too small and is typically android.

Comment: so I just want to use XP portably because a phone is too small.  A laptop isnt portable enough and Ive already had to send back a lenovo thinkppad running xp cause it was pre owned and had faults. I tried esxi on an i7 hp which had virtualization but it failed, apparently it only supports intel xeons or some amd cpus, also the gpus and sata controllers need to be on the esxi HCL

Comment: @Xalorous VMware Workstation offers excellent 3D support. ESXi is a bare-metal hypervisor and most definitely not what the OP wants *on* his Surface Book.

Comment: @legozebra From what I can find, the Surface Book is an UEFI-only device. Windows XP cannot work without BIOS. Try and get used to Windows 10 or just don’t use Windows at all. Using obsolete operating systems is not a good idea, especially in regards to security.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing what you're trying to accomplish may allow us to provide an answer that more closely meets your actual needs, but the accurate and complete answer to the question as it has been asked is this:

***Windows XP is not supported by NVidia for the GeForce GTX 965M GPU, either officially or unofficially.***